# Design for good relation between shader program and VAO

Tags: opengl

I am learning OpenGL and trying to get grasp of the best practices. I am working on a simple demonstration project in C++ which however aims to be a bit more generic and better structured (not everything just put in `main()`) than most of the tutorials I have seen on the web. I want to use the modern OpenGL ways which means VAOs and shaders. My biggest concern is about the relation of VAOs and shader programs. Maybe I am missing something here.

I am now thinking about the best design. Consider the following scenario:

- there is a scene which contains multiple objects
- each object has its individual size, position and rotation (i.e. transform matrix)
- each object has a certain basic shape (e.g. box, ball), there can be multiple objects of the same shape
- there can be multiple shader programs (e.g. one with plain interpolated RGBA colors, another with textures)

This leads me to the basic three components of my design:

- `ShaderProgram` class - each instance contains a vertex shader and fragment shader (initialized from given strings)
- `Object` class - has transform matrix and reference to a shape instance
- `Shape` base class - and derived classes e.g. `BoxShape`, `SphereShape`; each derived class knows how to generate its mesh and turn it into buffer and how to map it to vertex attributes, in other words it will initialize its own VAO; it also known which `glDraw...` function(s) to use to render itself

When a scene is being rendered, I will call `glUseProgram(rgbaShaderProgram)`. Then I will go through all objects which can be rendered using this program and render them. Then I will switch to `glUseProgram(textureShaderProgram)` and go through all textured objects.

When rendering an individual object:

1) I will call `glUniformMatrix4fv()` to set the individual transformation matrix (of course including projection matrix etc.)

2) then I will call the shape to which the object is associated to render

3) when shape is redered, it will bind its VAO, call its specific `glDraw...()` function and then unbind VAO

In my design I wanted to uncouple the dependency between `Shape` and `ShaderProgram` as they in theory can be interchangeable. But still some dependency seems to be there. When generating vertices in a specific `...Shape` class and setting buffers for them I already need to know that I for example need to generate texture coordinates rather than RGBA components for each vertex. And when setting vertex attribute pointers `glVertexAttribPointer` I already must know that the shader program will use for example floats rather than integers (otherwise I would have to call `glVertexAttribIPointer`). I also need to know which attribute will be at which location in the shader program. In other words I am mixing the responsibility for sole shape geometry and the prior knowledge about how it will be rendered. And as a consequence of this I cannot render a shape with a shader program which is not compatible with it.

So finally my question: how to improve my design to achieve the goal (render the scene) and at the same time keep the versatility (interchangeability of shaders and shapes), force the correct usage (not to allow mixing wrong shapes with incompatible shaders), have the best performance possible (avoid unnecessarry program or context switching) and maintain good design principles (one class - one responsibility).

Comment: This is really hard. My experience is that the problem lies in mixing functional requirements ("User want boxes and spheres") with infrastructure prerequisities ("Platform run faster with fewer context switches"). The solution is to ignore infrastructure prerequisities until needed and then make considerations on the application model, much like a C-compiler would without knowing its purpose. Let the infrastructure grow on need-basis from below the application instead of top-down functional context basis and you should be ok.

Comment: Hello V.K. I'm asking myself exactly the same question. Did you find any good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is prepare ShaderProgram(s) templates, which I adapt to VAO attributes.
After all, shader programs are text, initially. What you might do is write your main functions for vertex and fragment programs, and attach the "header" to them, depending on the bound VAO. It could be useful to use standardized names for the variables you use inside the shaders, such as InPos, InNor, InTan, InTex. 
That way, you can scan for elements that are missing in the VAO, but used inside the shader, and simply appending them in the header as const value with some default setting.
I do this via ShaderManager, with RequestShader(template,VAO) kind of function, which adapts the template to the VAO, and caches the compiled shader for later use.
If another VAO has the same attributes, and requires the same template, the precompiled cached version is returned to avoid the same adaptation process.